# Multiple modals with same script

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code that handles a modal opening and closing on a page. I would like to be able to load a second modal on the same page. It would have the same class ".custom-modal" but a different ID.

With my current code, both modals open but only the first modal is able to be closed.

```
var modal;
  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".customModalTrigger");
  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-close")[0];
  var body = document.body;

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  [].forEach.call(btns, function(el) {
    el.onclick = function() {
      // Get the modal
      modal = document.querySelector('#' + el.id + '.custom-modal');
      modal.classList.add('-show');
      body.classList.add('noscroll');
    }
  })

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
      modal.classList.remove('-show');
      body.classList.remove('noscroll');
  }
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("custom-close")[0]` this is only one x button. You should add onclick event handler to all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-close")[0];
```

Specifically, the `[0]`. You are only applying the event listener to the first matching element, and no others. Instead, try:

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-close");
for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++){
    span[i].onclick = = function() {
        modal.classList.remove('-show');
        body.classList.remove('noscroll');
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("custom-close")[0]` is only one x button. You should add onclick event handler to all of them

Something like this:

```
 var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-close");
 [].forEach.call(spans, function(el) {
     el.onclick = function() {
       modal.classList.remove('-show');
       body.classList.remove('noscroll');
     }
  })
```